# Sigfox data decode in c#

Tags: c#, decoding, endianness

I have a sigfox device and am trying to get the device to send the temperature to the sigfox backend and then get sigfox to email me the temperature.
Sigfox's webinar used the `tempt::float:32:little-endian` format,
this however spits out the following result in my email:

```
"Temperature" : -2.3514473E-36,
```

Even when I try to convert this on an online hex decimal converter, I get an error saying I have an Invalid hexadecimal value.

I Would like to know what data type this is and/or which format to use.

Comment: The data type of -2.3514473E-36 is a pointing float.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it to `Int32`. I do not work with temperature, but in other dimensions SigFox sends data in minimum dimension

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18544672)